# Attach VSCode debugger to .NET Core app debugging with Visual Studio IIS Express

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular app which uses .NET Core in the backend and Angular in the frontent. 
My team works the backend with Visual Studio 2019, but I prefer using VSCode for working with Angular. The thing is, to start the application, I do it via de Visual Studio IIS Express debugger, but then I can't establish breakpoints or anything of the like in VSCode.

I've seen in the VSCode Debugger that there are some options like "Attach to Chrome" which I think could be the way to stablish this connection with the running application but I don't really know if this is possible or how to do it. Hope you can help me with this and thank you all in advance.

Comment: why do you need to debug from vscode when Visual Studio gives you all functionalities like breakpoints etc

Comment: I just like it better, and if there's some way, I'd like to do it like this. If not, I'll stick with Visual Studio, but I just don't like as the debugging options for web apps as much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me with the latest update to Visual Studio 2017 Professional (v15.9.28307)

In Visual Studio setup a browser configuration for chrome with remote debugging enabled.

1. Click the dropdown next to the IIS Express launch button and select **Browse With...**
2. Add an instance for chrome with the argument `--remote-debugging-port=9222`

In VS Code

1. Install VS Code extension [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome)
2. Create a debug configuration to attach to your project's url in chrome and with the remote debug port you set in visual studio:

   ```json
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "type": "chrome",
               "request": "attach",
               "name": "Attach to Chrome",
               "url": "https://localhost:XXXX",
               "port":9222,
               "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
           }
       ] 
   }
   ```

Launch your application using your debug configuration from visual studio and then launch chrome dev tools.

From VS Code run the debugger attach configuration

Comment: I tried adding this configuration, but when I try to launch the app with the option "Launch browser" active, it gives me a connection error and doesn't launch. Here is a screenshot with the error and my .csproj configuration: https://gyazo.com/5c7726b4bd389cbc0e028c0f85b5caf2

If I do it without the "Launch browser" option, VSCode gives me just the same error on port 9222

Comment: I downloaded visual studio 2019 and looked at the verbose log (APPDATA\Local\Temp\vscode-chrome-debug.txt) and it looks like a `--remote-debugging-port=XXXX` argument is passed by default when IIS Express is launched. If you copy the port into the vscode configuration then the attach debug configuration should work, but the problem is the port changes every time IIS Express starts which is pretty inconvenient